# How to get UnsafeRawPointer on the swift object?

Tags: swift

My app uses the native C++ lib, there is a method that takes as an argument `void*`

```
void foo(void * obj) { ... }
```

in swift I can call this method like this

```
func boo(obj: MyCustomObj) {
    foo(&obj)
}
```

and looks like really I get a void pointer on the object, but if I try to get an `UnsafeRawPointer` on the object like this

```
func boo(obj: MyCustomObj) {
    var pointer = &obj           <----  Use of extraneous '&'
    foo(pointer)
}
```

I got an error

> Use of extraneous '&'

What is the problem here?

**EDIT**

I understood that using `withUnsafe***` I can get the pointer to the data, but what to do if my method has 2 params, would it looks like this

```
    withUnsafePointer(to: myObjFirst) {
      pFirst in
      withUnsafePointer(to: myObjSecond) {
        pSecond in
        foo(pFirst, pSecond)
      }
    }
```

Comment: What if you did something silly with the `pointer` variable (like returning it so it escapes from `boo`)?  Swift is designed so that things like that are very hard to do. To get a pointer, you can use one of the `withXXX` functions that take a closure (e.g. [`withUnsafeBytes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2998148-withunsafebytes)), and the pointer will only be valid inside the closure.

Comment: @Sweeper ok, got it, but the first example allows it, right? I mean if I pass the object by ref with `&` sign, so in this case swift allows to get the pointer on the object, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` syntax does not mean "the address of" or "pointer to" like in C. In Swift, it is an [in-out expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#grammar_in-out-expression).

These *can* be used to create [implicit pointer conversions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID632) as a convenience, and that can seem like C's "pointer to" meaning, but it has very different rules and behaviors. For example, there is no promise that `obj` even has an address. It may be a tagged pointer. Passing it via an in-out expression may allocate memory and copy the value to make the call possible. Similarly, when passing a "pointer to an array," Swift will actually pass a pointer to a contiguous block of values (which may have been copied to make them contiguous) which is not the same as the actual `Array` struct.

It is not meaningful to say `var pointer = &obj`. There is no in-out reference there.

There is no general way to take long-lived pointers to objects in Swift without allocating your own memory (and this is rare). The memory model doesn't promise the kinds of lifetimes you'd need to make that sensible. If your code did compile the way you expect it to, the call to `foo(pointer)` would still be invalid because there's no promise that `obj` exists at that point and the pointer could be dangling. (There are no references to `obj` after the first line, so Swift can and often will destroy it, even though it's still "in scope.")

The `foo(&obj)` syntax is basically a shorthand for:

```
withUnsafePointer(to: obj) { foo($0) }
```

It exists to make it easier to call C functions, but it doesn't mean that Swift pointers are anything like C pointers.

For much more on Swift pointers, see [Safely manage pointers in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10167) from WWDC 2020.

Comment: Thanks got it. I edited my question and added an example of the native method that gets 2 params, would the method look like in the question? I mean is it a proper approach?

Comment: Correct. That's exactly how you would do this for two parameters (and how you generally *should* do it for Swift functions; it's a more flexible approach). C functions have this happen a lot more, and it gets obnoxious, so the `&` syntax is a bit of a shortcut. `foo(&myObjFirst, &myObjSecond)`. But in many cases you don't even need the `&`. For the most common situations with `const` pointers and common C types, the compiler will just "fix" it for you if you just pass the value directly. (See the implicit pointer conversion link.)

Comment: From the link: "Using & instead of an explicit function like withUnsafePointer(to:) can help make calls to low-level C functions more readable, especially when the function takes several pointer arguments. However, when calling functions from other Swift code, avoid using & instead of using the unsafe APIs explicitly."