# How to cast back correctly a pointer (Swift & native)?

Tags: swift

I have a swift app where I use the native C++ lib and there is a method that takes as an argument `void *` on `MTLTexture`

```
void RenderAPI_Metal::EndModifyTexture(void* textureHandle)
{
    id<MTLTexture> tex = (__bridge id<MTLTexture>)textureHandle;
...
}
```

and Swift call is

```
func foo(texture: MTLTexture) {
...

  EndModifyTexture(&texture)
...
}
```

So, on the Swift side, I call the method and pass a pointer, and then on the C++ side when I try to cast it back I got an error

> om.apple.scenekit.scnview-renderer (20): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

So, according to the error looks like the pointer is nil, however, when I check it in the debug I see that it has an address `void* textureHandle` is `0x0000000280a08178`

What is the problem here? Why did I pass `MTLTexture` and then I got a problem casting it back?

**P.S.**

I can't change the implementation, C++ method should receive `void*`

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33294620/1187415.

Comment: This looks very close to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972527/how-to-get-unsaferawpointer-on-the-swift-object), you should not create many questions about the same problem but edit existing question with new details

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, but why do you think it is close to the previous question? The previous one is about the proper way to get a pointer on a certain swift object and this one is about how to cast the object back... I didn't get your suspicion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MartinR I found the solution here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33310021/5709159

exactly this method helps me to solve the problem

```
func bridgeRetained<T : AnyObject>(obj : T) -> UnsafeRawPointer {
    return UnsafeRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(obj).toOpaque())
}
```