# Send a SIMD4<Float> to a Metal buffer

Tags: swift, metal

I have a color defined as a `SIMD4<Float>` and would like to send it to a Metal buffer as shown below:

```swift
var color = SIMD4<Float>(1, 0, 0, 0)

var colorBuffer: MTLBuffer!

let size = MemoryLayout<SIMD4<Float>>.size
colorBuffer = Renderer.device.makeBuffer(bytes: color, length: size)
```

But this does not work because `bytes` must be an `UnsafeRawPointer` as seen from the error message provided by Xcode:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'SIMD4<Float>' to expected argument type 'UnsafeRawPointer'
```

So how do I get the `UnsafeRawPointer` for the `color` variable?

Comment: You should be able to pass the color var in with &color and it will be taken as a pointer. I have had some fun with metal function, buffers and pointers. Some take the &, others not. Some more info on the apple docs about halfway down showing the &. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsaferawpointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in the color var with an & which provides a pointer. eg.

```
colorBuffer = Renderer.device.makeBuffer(bytes: &color, length: size)
```

Comment: Yes, using `&color` works. Thanks. By the way, edit your answer so the code is in a code block. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more info.

Comment: Yep. Sorry. Forgot the code block. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `func storeBytes<T>(of: T, toByteOffset: Int, as: T.Type)` on the `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` that is returned by `contents` property of the `MTLBuffer` like this:

```
var color = SIMD4<Float>(1, 0, 0, 0)

var colorBuffer: MTLBuffer!

let size = MemoryLayout<SIMD4<Float>>.size
colorBuffer = Renderer.device.makeBuffer(bytes: color, length: size)
colorBuffer.contents.storeBytes(of: color, toByteOffset: 0, as:SIMD4<Float>.self)
```

Comment: Why not use `&color` as mentioned in the other answer?

Comment: @wigging it's not safe!

Comment: > Why not use &color as mentioned in the other answer?
This gives you more flexibility as to an offset you can put the things at. Obviously, you can create a buffer with bytes, but you don't always have the data at the point where you are creating the `MTLBuffer`. Anyway, there isn't really anything Metal specific here. As soon as you get `contents` from a buffer, it's just regular Swift and unsafe pointers. You can load, store, use `&` and other syntax, because at that point it's just a pointer to the compiler, not some `MTLBuffer `.

Comment: More info here on using & here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972527/how-to-get-unsaferawpointer-on-the-swift-object

Comment: It's an UnsafeRawPointer by definition in the function so of course it is unsafe. As per the apple documentation for UnsafeRawPointer - quote " Alternatively, you can use Swift’s implicit bridging to pass a pointer to an instance or to the elements of an array. Use inout syntax to implicitly create a pointer to an instance of any type.." Wrong quote previously. This is from: developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsaferawpointer . Your code above fails with the same error on the function: colorBuffer = Renderer.device.makeBuffer(bytes: color, length: size)

Comment: This does not work and gives the same error as mentioned in the original question.